# tableViewController on button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a `tableViewController`, the cells contains a button and a label. I need to get the text of the cell (actually the object of the cell `Person`) when the user clicks on the button.

When the user clicks on the button the following method gets executed;

```
-(void) buttonOfCellClicked{
      // here i need to access the `Person` object that the user clicked
 }
```

How do i write this code?

EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Person *person = [personsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 75, 60)];
label.text =person.firstName;   
[cell addSubview:label];
UIButton *button= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOfCellClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:button];


}
```

Comment: can you show your "cell for row at index path" code?

Comment: i have updated the code above

Answer (score 6):

```
id findAncestor(UIView *view, Class class) {
    while (view && ![view isKindOfClass:class])
        view = [view superview];
    return view;
}

- (void)buttonOfCellClicked:(UIButton *)button
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)findAncestor(button, [UITableViewCell class]);
    UITableView *table = (UITableView *)findAncestor(cell, [UITableView class]);
    NSIndexPath *path = [table indexPathForCell:cell];
    if (!path)
        return;
    Person *person = [personsArr objectAtIndex:path.row];
    // do whatever with person
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass UITableviewCell and add a property and the action to that class and in IB connect the button. When you are configuring the cell just set the person object. This approach would depend heavily on what you plan on doing with that object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask your button to tell you where it is. To achieve this, you need to call `superview` twice (1x will return cell.contentView, 2x will return cell):

```
- (void)buttonOfCellClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    UITabvleViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
}
```

Then you can access cell's properties e.g. `cell.textLabel.text`

---

EDIT: You also need to add `:` to your `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` in `cellForRow` after `buttonOfCellClicked` text:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOfCellClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

---

EDIT2: you can access person by

```
NSIndexPath *ip = [yourTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
Person *p = [personArr objectAtIndex:ip.row];
```

Comment: Is there anyway for me to access the object and not its property ? for instance the cell gets populated with `Person.firstName` etc. i need to get the object `Person` selected

Comment: There is a Label as well, and it gets populated like `Person.firstName`. There is an Array of `Person` objects, and the label gets populated like `Person.firstName`.

Comment: Could you post the whole `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code, please?

Answer (score -1):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [yourArray count];\
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

UIButton *button= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTag:indexPath.row]; // SET TAG TO YOUR BUTTON, IT WILL BE SAME AS YOUR OBJECT AT INDEX OF ARRAY
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOfCellClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:button];


}

-(void) buttonOfCellClicked:(id) sender{
     Person *person = [yourArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
      // here i need to access the `Person` object that the user clicked
 }
```

Comment: This will stop working if the contents of yourArray can change - for example, if elements can be deleted.

Comment: Whenever your remove/delete object from array you'll have to refresh the tableView to show current results. So it'll work :)

Comment: You can delete rows from the table using -[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:].  You don't have to refresh the whole table view.