# How to set Action for UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have `XIB` file **TimerCell.xib** with `UITableViewCell`. In other class in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** I initialize this `UITableViewCell`:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellTimer";
    TimerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell = [[TimerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimerCell"owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

In my **TimerCell** I have two `UILabel` and one `UIButton`. For this button I would like to set **action** to some method.

How can I do that? And how to show in the first `UILabel` the data from my background countdown timer in real time?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This piece of code will help you

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellTimer";
TimerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    //cell = [[TimerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimerCell"owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.tag=indexPath.row;
   [button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   [button setTitle:@"cellButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 0.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
   }

  return cell;
}


-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender
{
 NSLog(@"I Clicked a button %d",sender.tag);
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: it works! Thank you!! How to set tag for it now? Before it was **cell.staticButton.tag = indexPath.row;**

Answer (score 15):

Since you have a subclass of `UITableViewCell` named `TimerCell`, you can add outlet properties to `TimerCell`.  For example:

```
@interface TimerCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label;

@end
```

In `TimerCell.xib`, connect the outlets to the button and the label.

Then, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you can easily access the button to set its target and action:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellTimer";
TimerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimerCell"owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonWasTapped:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];;
```

You can access the cell's label using its `label` property to update it when the timer fires.

Another way to get at the button and the label is to use view tags, as I described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8291867/77567).

In `cellButtonWasTapped:` (or whatever action you send from the button), you'll probably want to look up the index path of the cell containing the button.  I explain how to do that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881028/77567).

Comment: I don't understand how can I show current timer value in UITableViewCell... can you explain this again. For more details: timer works in singleton. There is only 1 timer, but there is a Dictionary with several items which contain time values. Every minute timer decrements 1 from all items in dictionary. TimerCell is a tableView's cell which appears in pop-up. So I would like to show dictionary's item's time values in my cell.label... Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653729/how-to-show-nstimers-time-value-in-uitableviewcells-label

Comment: +1 for great explanation and documentation... 10 more to go with you 119,000 ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellTimer";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    NSInteger index = indexPath.row;
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(MethodName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

And set UIButton and UILabel's tag in your XIB file TimerCell.xib

Answer (score -3):

Please do better research before posting on SO.
Here is the code to add Button to cell

```
UIButton *Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(MethodName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[Button setTitle:@"ButtonTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
Button.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 10.0, 40.0, 40.0);
[cell.contentView addSubview:Button];
```

Comment: Why is it downvoted? Please explain or it is useless. Is it wrong? Does it answer or try to answer the question?