# How to set IBAction for a UIButton in a UITableViewCell for a different ViewController?

Tags: swift

I have subclassed UITableViewCell. Here I have made an outlet for a button. When that button have been clicked on, it should execute a function in a different ViewController. I have tried this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    reloadTableView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(multiplayerChannelView.tappedOnReloadTableView), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

However, this crashes with this error:

[test.CreateChannelCell tappedOnReloadTableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc1198b5200

The function exists, with no typo. Why does this not work? This question looks the same only it is not written in swift 3.0 [How to set Action for UIButton in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652133/how-to-set-action-for-uibutton-in-uitableviewcell)

multiplayerChannelView is the viewcontroller which holds the UITableView. I got a seperated .swift file with the UITableViewCell subclassed.

Comment: Is `multiplayerChannelView` is your controller where you are populating data in tableView?

Comment: Yesssssssssssss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.your_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tappedButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside);
```

And anywhere in the same UIVeiwController define the function as below

```
func tappedButton(sender : UIButton){
// Your code here
}
```

Comment: I get the error value of type UITableViewCell has no member X. However, I have set an outlet in my UITableViewCell.

Comment: cell.your_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tappedButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside);

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by creating `delegate` in your `tableViewCell` class.

```
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
func buttonPressed ()
}
```

then initialize your delegate like below in your `tableViewCell`

```
var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate?
```

and for button action put below code in your `tableViewCell` class

```
@IBAction func cellButtonPressed (sender : UIButton) {
            if (self.delegate != nil) {
                self.delegate?.buttonPressed()
    }
```

On button click check wether delegate is not nil , please set `cell.delegate = self` in `cellForRowAtIndex` method

In the last just add code for button action in your classes where you have used `customTableViewCell` class

```
extension ViewController : CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
        func buttonPressed () {
            // Perfom your code on button action
        }
}
```

your `CustomTableViewCellDelegate` looks like below:

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
    func buttonPressed ()
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func cellButtonPressed (sender : UIButton) {
        if (self.delegate != nil) {
            self.delegate?.buttonPressed()
    }

}
```

Hope it work for you!

Comment: I have no idea where to put all the functions. When I try to add the cell.delegate = self I get an error: Value of type UITableViewCell has no member 'delegate'. Where to put the var delegate, at what VC? and where to put the IBAction function? I tried adding the var delegate in both viewcontrollers, still no luck

Answer (score 1):

write below code in file VC2

```
 import UIKit
 class tblCell : UITableViewCell
{

@IBOutlet weak var btnAction: UIButton!
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    print(sender.tag) // you can identify your cell from sender.tag value

    // notification is fire here and call notification from VC1
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "buttonAction"), object: nil)
}
}

class VC2: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{

@IBOutlet weak var tblview: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tblview.delegate = self
    tblview.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: -  Table veiw
func tableView(_ tblBlog: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 10

}

func tableView(_ tblBlog: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell : tblCell = tblview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! tblCell

    cell.btnAction.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
    //
}

}
```

write below code in file VC1

```
class VC1: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    // this notification is call when it fire from VC2
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ButtonClick), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "buttonAction"), object: nil)
}
func ButtonClick()
{
    // code when button is clicked you wanto perfrom
}
}
```

Comment: No this is not how it works I get all kind of errors

Comment: Please try and give more details in your answer - code snippets will help