# Why does it return only one uid when tapping a button inside the tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My problem that I present to you is that, I have a button inside a table View Cell and when tapped a person name it displays the current user uid but the things is, when I tap a different person name it should return that user uid not the current one, Can you please help me fix this bug
Thank you in advance, feel free to ask for more code is you don't fully understand my code

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}     




 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


     //This is a button inside the tableView cell
    cell.buttonName.setTitle(array[indexPath.section].uid ,for: .normal)
    //this is putting the name inside another ViewController label and display its name 
    self.secondViewController.name.text = array[indexPath.section].uid
 cell.buttonName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addName), for: .touchUpInside) 
 }
   let person = secondViewController()


@objc func addName() {

    person.name.text = array[?].uid
    profiler.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true


}
```

Comment: Hey, Did you mean to put the code in the DidSelect Method from the tableview? Now you are using the CellForRowAt, that must return a TableViewCell.
That code will be executed every time you scroll the tableview to configure every cell with the desired data.

Comment: Would it work if the button is inside the cell?

Comment: @BrunoLoops can you show how would it work. Remind you that is a button inside the tableView Cell that is goin g to be pressed not the cell itself.

Comment: First of all, in the `cellForRowAt` method you should return a UITableViewCell.
Then you have two options, change the name on the secondViewController when the cell is selected (when tapped in any place on the cell the name would be changed) then you need to use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or use the button action by passing a selector (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652133/how-to-set-action-for-uibutton-in-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Are you using interface builder?

Comment: Nope, I am doing everything programmatically, the link that you provide is in objective c can you do one in swift because I am more familiar with swift than c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a method that makes the action that you need, and add this action to the button

```
func updatePersonName(_ button:UIButton) {
    self.secondViewController.name.text = button.titleLabel.text
}     

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


     //This is a button inside the tableView cell
    cell.buttonName.setTitle(array[indexPath.section].uid ,for: .normal)
    //We remove all actions added to this button (reuse)
    cell.buttonName.removeTarget(self, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
    //Add new target
    cell.buttonName.addTarget(self, action:#selector(updatePersonName), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
 }
```

Comment: what is cell.buttonName.argOne = indexPath.section

Comment: You need to save somewhere the section, so you can retrieve the data that you need.
The @objc is just to make this function available from Objc code
If you need to you can use it (won't affect the behavior)

Comment: hmmm... You could use a property to save that info... let me edit my answer

Comment: The best solution would be to move the updatePersonName method inside a CustomCell class (that gets configured with a person) and calls the View Controller with the data (name or uid) that you need to update the secondViewController

Comment: The argOne option should be to extend the Button to add a argument to pass through the event

Comment: This button is enhance to the tableView cell meaning it doesn't come straight from the tableView cell that is why the argOne doesn't come I made my custom cell with is the button that I put

Comment: The updatePersonName function says the button is unresolved identifier because it has not been use yet

Comment: your answer did not help at all

Comment: Hi @JoseGarcia I mixed up the order in the updatePersonName function

Comment: The behavior you want should be separated through views.
I think I explained pretty good your problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400710/why-does-it-return-only-one-uid-when-tapping-a-button-inside-the-tableviewcell/57401814#comment101284661_57400710) and the best solution, if you read more carefully it explains why you are getting that behavior.